# Eloquera database Compact - constant growth of the database size

Tags: database, testing, fragmentation, object-oriented-database, eloquera

I am evaluating Eloquera (desktop mode) for usage in our project. My unit tests perform some kind of stress-testing, e.g. I store 1000 records and delete them in the end of the test. Each time I run the tests, the database size grows, although in fact no records are there (they are all being deleted in the end of the tests). Of course, I checked that there are actually no records there by querying the database. I can assume that some kind of fragmentation takes place, but it seems to me that there should be some way to get rid of this fragmentation...

I thought maybe Compact() function should do the job, and maybe it is called somehow automatically, because it is not recommended to call it manually "Compact is a system operation, and should not be used in the CRUD cycle." But I executed the tests several times, so that my "empty" database reached 1 GB size, and the size continues to grow further.

Then I tried to call Compact() manually before closing the database on finishing my application. After that I was not able to open the database any more: Eloquera.Common.EloqueraException: Virtual Filesystem: Corrupted header

Do I miss something?

I use version 6.3.3 as a NuGet Package (desktop mode).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also have the problem, when I call Compact() manually :(